# why "php -i|grep php.ini" is not finding the correct path to php.ini?

Tags: php, centos, centos5, php.ini

I know that my php.ini is located at `/etc/php.ini` but when i run `php -i|grep php.ini` I get this output

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
```

there's nothing in that directory and i know where my php.ini is located, so why am i getting this output?

Answer (score 2):

When you run "which php" what does it give as an answer? How did you install php? It sounds like you have 2 versions of php running on your server.

Comment: "which php" gives this output '/usr/local/bin/php' it's just a file, but in '/usr/local/lib' i have a folder called php with many files folders inside it, I am using php 5.3.8 and i deleted the previous version (or at least that what i think lol) should i delete the file called php in usr local bin? that's how i upgraded to the latest version http://nix.michaelslist.org/?p=31

Comment: and installed the previous php version like this

"yum install php php-mysql php-common php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-devel php-xml"

Comment: Sounds like your php is installed in /usr/local/lib/php with the php.ini in /usr/local/lib/php/php.ini

Comment: "/usr/local/lib/php/" exists but there's no php.ini inside that php foloder, anyway how to get rid of it, i only need 1 php do i just delete it or what?

Comment: and one more thing, what version will i be deleting? :D