# Apache not working

Tags: php, centos, php5, apache-2.2

i have centos 5...php 5.3.8 and apache 2.2.21...I had [this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/317190/the-url-requested-was-not-found-on-this-server) now i have another problem... first of all i see apache test page even though my script is still there ( but that problem i can fix), but apache is not working, if you go to [showpill.com/hi.php](http://www.showpill.com/hi.php) you can see that apache is not working

Comment: hi.php actually shows that Apache is working - we wouldn't see anything if it wasn't, just a "server not responding" error. You just haven't configured mod_php properly.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: @Rilindo of course man!!!

Comment: I have to be sure. :)

Comment: Wait, how did you install PHP? Through yum or did you compile it from scratch?

Comment: @Rilindo Both. See his other question: http://serverfault.com/questions/313927/why-php-igrep-php-ini-is-not-finding-the-correct-path-to-php-ini

Comment: Based on the current version on CentOS 5, he is using the compiled version. It sounds like php module is not enabled in Apache.

Comment: @Rilindo i installed it using yum but then when i installed the newest version i removed the old one and compiled the new one from source so the current one is installed from source

Comment: Okay, in that case, look at @Lazy Badger's response, as that is the fix there.

Comment: Small request: show result of `rpm -qi php` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache working. You have not finished mod_php configuration. In minimal form it's something like

```
PHPIniDir "path here"
LoadModule php5_module "path to module"
AddType application/x-httpd-php phtml php
```

Comment: sir where to find mod_php in order to configure it? and you said In minimal form it's something like that so what is the ideal form then?

Comment: Know nothing about CentOS, but - if you know there to find httpd.conf, you can open it and see at strings LoadModule (module have relative path before filename). PHP module must be (if apache-package compiled w|php)at the same (?) location. Last action after solving troubles will be  addidng index.php to base DirectoryIndex

Comment: It seems /usr/lib/php/modules/ is CentOS path, but must be tested

Comment: my vps has expired and the other will expire very soon so I'll get a new one and start over...